# Factoring variables from fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was working on a problem that I got wrong to solve for the variable N. The solution is as follows:

$$\left(\frac{12-N}{10}\right)+\left(\frac{-N}{20}\right)+\left(\frac{6-N}{10}\right) =0$$

$$36-5N=0$$

$$N=7.2$$

Where I am lost is from the first step to the second. I thought I could factor out N from the numerator and only need to solve the fractions but apparently that did not work as I got N(11/4). Could someone please explain how they got to 36-5N?

Comment: Try multiplying both sides of the equation by $20$.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you. I definitely over thought it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear how do you factor our $N$ directly, since you did not explain how did you factor $N$ out from $12-N$ and $6-N$.

Make the denominator to be the same first.

$$\frac{24-2N}{20}-\frac{N}{20}+\frac{12-2N}{20}=0$$

Multiply by $20$,

$$24-2N-N+12-2N=0$$

this will give you,

$$36-5N=0$$